# Set selected Option Angular 4+ in Chrome

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a selected value of an option retrieved from a DB and passed into an @Input. The value is correctly passed into the control but the option is never set - defaults to first value.

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ISuburbDto } from '../types';
import { SuburbDataService } from '../venues/suburbs/suburb-data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'suburbs-list',
    template: ` 
    <select type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="emit()"   name="suburb" 
    #suburb="ngModel">
    <option *ngFor="let suburb of suburbs" [ngValue]="suburb" [selected]="selected && suburb.id == selected.id">{{suburb.name}}</option>
</select>`
})
export class SuburbsDropDownList implements OnInit {


    public suburbs: Array<ISuburbDto>;

    @Output()
    valueChanged: EventEmitter<ISuburbDto> = new EventEmitter<ISuburbDto>();

    @Input()
    selected: ISuburbDto;

    constructor(private suburbDataService: SuburbDataService) {
        this.suburbs = new Array<ISuburbDto>();

    }

    emit() {
        this.valueChanged.emit(this.selected);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.suburbDataService.getAllSuburbs().subscribe(x => this.suburbs = x);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Don't use [selected] in your view. The truth is in the model: if the `selected`field is **the same object** (as in `===`) as one of the suburbs, then it will be selected. That's what you need to achieve: store one of the suburbs of the array in the `selected` field.

Comment: Thank you, this principle worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows:

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected" [value]="suburbs[0]" (ngModelChange)="emit()" name="suburb" 
    #suburb="ngModel">
    <option *ngFor="let suburb of suburbs" [ngValue]="suburb" [selected]="selected && suburb.id == selected.id">{{suburb.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `value` property to the select:

`<select [value]="suburbs[0]">`